# Can login to sftp, but not to ssh shell

Tags: server, ssh, openssh, sftp

I was trying to setup a new sftp user for my server (Ubuntu 20.04). I created the user `my-user`, added a public key to his `.ssh/authorized_keys` file and decided to test an SSH login before anything.. and to my great surprise, Putty closes connection right after a succesful login

I attempted to ssh from a Windows PowerShell and got the same result (disconnect right after a succesful login)

Finally, I tried to sftp with this login... and that works perfectly fine, I remain connected

I haven't setup sftp restrictions at all for this user so I am clueless as to what causes this..

Here is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
AllowAgentForwarding no
#AllowGroups sudo
AllowTcpForwarding no
Banner /etc/issue.net
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr
ClientAliveCountMax 0
ClientAliveInterval 3600
Compression no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
KerberosAuthentication no
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
LogLevel VERBOSE
LoginGraceTime 20
Macs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 10
MaxStartups 10:30:60
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PermitRootLogin no
PermitUserEnvironment no
Port 22
PrintLastLog yes
PrintMotd no
RekeyLimit 512M 1h
StrictModes yes
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
TCPKeepAlive no
UseDNS no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding no
```

Here is the only other config file that gets included:

```
PermitRootLogin no
DebianBanner no
Protocol 2
LoginGraceTime 10
PasswordAuthentication no
ClientAliveInterval 3600
ClientAliveCountMax 0
AllowUsers ubuntu my-user
X11Forwarding no
```

Finally, here is the output from `ssh -vvv my-user@myip` after authentication:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ([XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:437 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:437 to 65001
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/my-user/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 437
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 437
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 437
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 437
Connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX closed.
Transferred: sent 2912, received 2632 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 8646.7, received 7815.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted after 2 hours of struggle, found the solution 5 min later, classic..

For those who might encounter the same issue: check your `/etc/passwd` file. The shell for this user was defined as `/bin/false`, which returns an error upon SSH login.

In my case, the distribution is hardened and the `/etc/adduser.conf` file that sets defaults had been modified to set the shell path to `/etc/passwd` for new users.

Comment: Well done reporting back.  That is great for this community.